# line spacing in label (autosize = false) C#

Tags: c#, label, double, space

I know its possible to do line spacing in Label. Can someone help me do this pls? 
I need a label with double spacing or 1.5 spacing.

I found this code but its not working:

```
    private void label1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        string text = "Sri Lanka";
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Font font = new Font("Arial", 10);
        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
        float lineSpacing = 0.5f;

        SizeF size = g.MeasureString("A", font);

        float pos = 0.0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; ++i)
        {
            string charToDraw = new string(text, 1);
            g.DrawString(charToDraw, font, brush, pos, 0.0f);
            SizeF sizeChar = g.MeasureString(charToDraw, font);
            pos += sizeChar.Width + size.Width * lineSpacing;
        }
    }
```

It gives me the error: **the best overloaded match for 'string.string(char, int)' has some invalid arguments** on this code "**string charToDraw = new string(text, 1);**".

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are passing a string as the first parameter and there is no overloaded string constructor that takes a string as the first parameter.

If you are trying to access the string character by character, try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; ++i)
{
    char charToDraw = text[i];
```

But if you are trying to pass it character by character to DrawString() you will need a string version of the single char, so it would be easier to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; ++i)
{
    string charToDraw = text.SubString(i, 1);
```

Comment: its not working either. :(
All I want is a label to have double spacing. Im using a multiline label (autosize = false).

Comment: Well the owner-draw stuff is pretty fiddly - Have you read-up on Owner Draw? I'm not sure a Label even supports it.